# What hook do I use to edit the post statuses option in admin?

Tags: filters, wp-admin, hooks

I want to restrict pending posts to only certain users in the admin section, so I want to remove it from the post status options when viewing all posts (the bit highlighted in red in the image below):

[image: WordPress post statuses submenu]

However, I can't find which hook I need to edit this. Can anyone shunt me in the right direction? I've scanned the filter reference but didn't see anything appropriate.

Comment: I see [`register_post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status) have a couple arguments ie `show_in_admin_all_list` and `show_in_admin_status_list`, but I don't know what the best hook to play around this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the filter `views_edit-post` (or `views_edit-{custom-post-type}`) to modify the available "views":

```
add_filter('views_edit-post', 'cyb_remove_pending_filter' );
function cyb_remove_pending_filter( $views ) {
    if( isset( $views['pending'] ) ) {
        unset( $views['pending'] );
    }
    return $views;
}
```

In the above filter you need inlude the user rules you want to apply. For exmple, if you want to remove the "Pending" view only for users who can not edit others posts:

```
add_filter('views_edit-post', 'cyb_remove_pending_filter' );
function cyb_remove_pending_filter( $views ) {
    if( isset( $views['pending'] ) && ! current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
        unset( $views['pending'] );
    }
    return $views;
}
```

Also, if you exclude the pending view, you need to update the "All" post count:

```
add_filter('views_edit-post', 'cyb_remove_pending_filter' );
function cyb_remove_pending_filter( $views ) {

    if( isset( $views['pending'] ) && ! current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {
        unset( $views['pending'] );

        $args = [
            // Post params here
            // Include only the desired post statues for "All"
            'post_status' => [ 'publish', 'draft', 'future', 'trash' ],
            'all_posts'   => 1,
        ];
        $result = new WP_Query($args);

        if($result->found_posts > 0) {

            $views['all'] = sprintf( 
                                '<a href="%s">'.__('All').' <span class="count">(%d)</span></a>',
                             admin_url('edit.php?all_posts=1&post_type='.get_query_var('post_type')),
                             $result->found_posts
            );

        }
    }

    return $views;
}
```

This code only remove the filter in the screen but it doesn't block the access to the post with pending status. To block the access you need to use `pre_get_posts` action. For example:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cyb_exclude_pending_posts' );
function cyb_exclude_pending_posts( $query ) {

    // only in admin, main query and if user can not edit others posts
    if( is_admin() && ! current_user_can('edit_others_posts') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Include only the desired post statues
        $post_status_arg = [ 'publish', 'draft', 'future', 'trash' ];
        $query->set( 'post_status', $post_status_arg );
    }

}
```

Comment: This solution certainly works, but I do wonder... Why do you need to run an additional query? The results of the main query are stored within the `$GLOBALS['posts']` aren't they? So to reduce queries, is it not a better idea to loop through `$GLOBALS['posts'] and count all within the desired status? I could be wrong... I have always done this the way you describe but looking at all options to reduce queries in one of my plugins and this could be one way?

Comment: The global variable includes posts for current query, but have several counters that may or may not be equal to current query.

Comment: is there any way to handle "mine" link, i want to show mine link only if the posts have two or more authors.

Answer (score 2):

The filter you are looking for is `views_{$this->screen->id}` which is located in the `WP_List_Table::views()` method.

Where `$this->screen->id` is that of the context you are in, e.g. `posts`, `users`, etc...

File `wp-admin/class-wp-list-table.php`

Example usage:

```
function filter_posts_listable_views($views) {
    //do your thing...

    return $views;
}

add_filter( 'views_posts', 'filter_posts_list_table_views', 100);
```